# How to match from a word up to the end of a sentence?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, string

I'd like to take the entire of sentence after the word "is" with python regex python.

My code:

```
s = '''Robert is an English actor, model and musician.
He started his film career by playing Cedric Diggory in Harry Potter.'''
r = re.findall(r'(?:is) (.*)',s)
print(r)
```

I expect the output to be:

```
'an English actor, model and musician'
```

But the actual output is:

```
['an English actor, model and musician','film career by playing Cedric Diggory in Harry Potter']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use word boundaries around `is` so only `is` matches as whole word and not partially in some other word like it is matching with `his` (which is not intended) and use this regex,

```
\bis\s+([^.]*)
```

Without word boundaries, even `his` matches and gives you the second sentence that you don't want.

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kM3Xch/4)**

Try this modified Python code,

```
import re

s = '''Robert is an English actor, model and musician.
He started his film career by playing Cedric Diggory in Harry Potter.'''
r = re.findall(r'\bis\s+([^.]*)',s)
print(r)
```

Prints only,

```
['an English actor, model and musician']
```

Comment: The expected output in the question does **not** include a dot!

Comment: @AmirA.Shabani: Very easy to handle. Just need to use `[^.]` instead of `.` Let me update my post. You have eagle's eyes :)

Comment: @AmirA.Shabani: Updated. Check now.

Comment: You only really need the leading `\b`. The trailing one is implicit in the space that must always follow `is`

Comment: And that `(?: ... )` (non-capturing group) isn't needed there ... ?  Altogether `r'\bis\s+([^.]+)'` should be fine --- given that this must be a simple-minded take, disregarding all the language issues like `Mrs. ` etc.  (The `+` since there's got to be something there for a reasonable sentence.)

Comment: @MadPhysicist: Oh, yes you're right. `\b` after `is` is not needed as it is followed by space anyway. Updated post. Thanks for good suggestion :)

Comment: @zdim: Correct, further pruned the regex. Good observation. Thanks for suggestion. Post updated.

Answer (score 1):

As you only wish to get from `is` upto the end of sentence, [this RegEx](https://regex101.com/r/yn932l/2) will work:

```
\bis\s+(.+?)\.
```

which need be used with the flag `s` so that `.` matches newlines as well, in case a sentence is spread over multiple lines.   I use `+` quantifier with `.` since `.*` would make the whole regex match even with nothing between `is` and `.`, what wouldn't make sense for a sentence.

[image]

The `.` is removed from your output by moving it out of the capturing parenthesis. The "rest of the sentence" is in the first capture group.

Please note though that a simple approach like this won't work if there are things like `Mrs.` in the sentence (and there are many phrases that contain the `.` that may belong in a sentence).

Parsing a natural language is very difficult. If you have 
anything more complex than a simple, well defined, and predictable text then you should reach for a dedicated library.  A quick search reveals, for example, comprehensive libaries [NLTK](https://www.nltk.org/) and [spaCy](https://spacy.io/).

---

[This helpful regex tool](https://regex101.com/r/YtHXQT/1) offers explanation of how it matches. A variation of your attempt

```
(\bis\b)([\s\S]*)
```

[image]

See the linked page for details.  Comments

- It creates two capturing group, where your target output is the second group, and you might call it using <kbd>$2</kbd>.
- The first group creates a word boundary around your only instance of <kbd>is</kbd>.
- You might escape any language specific metachars using <kbd>\</kbd>.

Comment: The "second group" is exactly what they're already getting and trying to avoid!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55896959/how-to-match-from-a-word-up-to-the-end-of-a-sentence/55897108#comment98451338_55897108

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to use [`partition()`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/partition):

```
splice = s.partition("is")[2]  # an English actor, model and musician. He started his film career by playing Cedric Diggory in Harry Potter.
```

then `split()`:

```
final = splice.split('.')[0]
```

Comment: This answer is not correct. 1) OP explicitly mentioned using *regex.* 2) The output is not "an English actor, model and musician"

Answer (score -1):

This results because `.*` is greeady and match all rest if it can (and it can).

Since you have new line separation you can use it for your needs.
Using regexp for this string only you can do it like this using Positive Lookbehind `(?<=is)`. *will match but does not include into results*

```
s = '''Robert is an English actor, model and musician.
He started his film career by playing Cedric Diggory in Harry Potter.'''
r = re.findall(r'(?<=is).*\n',s)
print(r)
[' an English actor, model and musician.\n']
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55896959/how-to-match-from-a-word-up-to-the-end-of-a-sentence/55897108#comment98451338_55897108